# Can't obtain div style width or height

Tags: javascript

I don't know why but I can't set the canvas width and height, and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I create the page like this:

```
//create div
var d = document.createElement('div'); 
d.id = 'G';
d.className = 'GameOuput';  
document.getElementById('E').appendChild(d);    

var i = 1;
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.id = 'layer' + i;
    c.className = 'c';
    c.style['z-index'] = i;

    document.getElementById('G').appendChild(c);  

    console.log(document.getElementById('G').style.width);  
    c.width = document.getElementById('G').style.width;
    c.height = document.getElementById('G').style.height;
```

The the canvas shows:

```
<canvas id="layer1" class="c" style="z-index: 1;" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
```

`console.log(document.getElementById('G').style.width);` = blank

What am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('G').offsetWidth;
```

Typically, an element's `offsetWidth` is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width.